# "npm prune --no-production" as "npm ci/install" command alternative

Tags: npm

I came across a CI pipeline that used `npm prune --no-production` instead of `npm ci` or `npm install`. I was surprised that it worked as I believed that prune just removes the "extraneous" packages, but it actually installs non-extraneous packages as well. Should npm prune ever be used instead of ci on a pipeline, or install locally?